# Gradle Does not find object "No such property"

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying build my first `buildSrc` Structure for a test project and try to follow a structure which comes from an official Android example:
https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Crane/buildSrc/src/main/java/com/example/crane/buildsrc/Dependencies.kt

So this is my Structure:

```kotlin
object Versions {
    const val gradle_version = "7.0.2"
    const val kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    const val compose_version = "1.0.1"
}

object Libs {
    object AndroidX {
        object Core {
            const val lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
            const val activity_version = "1.3.0-alpha06"
            const val core_version = "1.3.2"
            const val appcompat_version = "1.2.0"

            const val lifecycle = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:${lifecycle_version}"
            const val activity = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:${activity_version}"
            const val core = "androidx.core:core-ktx:${core_version}"
            const val appcompat = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${appcompat_version}"
        }

        object Compose {
            const val ui = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${Versions.compose_version}"
            const val material = "androidx.compose.material:material:${Versions.compose_version}"
            const val ui_preview =
                "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:${Versions.compose_version}"
        }
    }

    object Material {
        const val material_version = "1.3.0"
        const val material = "com.google.android.material:material:${material_version}"
    }
}
```

`Versions.kotlin_version` does work without problems.
Strange part is that the IDE drops sometimes a warning on my `Core` Object which says "Redundant empty class body". And when I try to sync, I get an error `No such property: AndroidX for class: Libs`

Thats how I wrote the dependencies in the `build.gradle (:app)`:

```
dependencies {

    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Core.lifecycle
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Core.activity
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Core.core
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Core.appcompat
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.ui
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.material
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.ui_preview
    implementation Libs.Material.material
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:${Versions.compose_version}"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Versions.compose_version}"
}
```

My guess is that I have some really basic error somewhere which I don't see.

Comment: Do you have the same error when running Gradle from the command line? Or is it IDE-only? If it's only in the IDE, I guess it might just be synchronization issues between Gradle and the IDE.

Comment: Also, just for the record, there is an incubating Gradle feature called [versions catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:conventional-dependencies-toml) to do what you're doing without `buildSrc`. You can simply declare all of that in a TOML file, and use type-safe accessors from Gradle. If you want to try it out, you'll need the `VERSION_CATALOGS` feature flags as mentioned at the top of the page

Comment: @Joffrey 1) Its also from command line. 2) Thats for the tip, but ill try to go easy in the first step and will level up my game when i know how this exatcly works

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and fixed it by convert build.gradle to build.gradle.kts.